# Updating a jar file with a new .class files

Tags: java, jar

I have a Jar file which contains multiples .class files.
I want to update one of the .class file with a new one, I used the command:

```
jar uf jar-file input-file(s)
```

My problem is that others classes use some functions defined in the updated class file and after updating it seems that I can't call any method of the updated class. Please have a look on my example below:

**class1.java:**

```
package com.package1;

class1 
{ 
   void method1()
   {
      System.out.println("In method1");  
   }
}
```

**class2.java:**

```
package com.package2; 
import com.package1.class1; 

class2 
{ 
   void method2()
   {
      class1 cl1 = new class1();

      cl1.method1(); //<<<<<< This line doesn't work after updating class1, program exits.
   }
}
```

**- MyJar.jar:**

```
      class1.class  
      class2.class
```

Do I need to recompile all classes of the jar?

Comment: Are the two classes in the default package (root of the JAR)? Otherwise you also have to set the package in your updated classes.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering! The updated class is not in the default package. I am not sure to understand what you mean by ''Set the package"

Comment: I was referring to the package declaration that you just added to your question. As we are talking about classes in two different packages don't forget to mark the class (and the relevant methods) as `public`...

Answer (score 0):

Will work on OS having drag-n-drop feature.

If you have 7-zip software installed (or maybe any archive viewer), then

open the jar file with 7-zip -> navigate to the package -> drag and drop the .class file

Comment: Hi! The problem is that I'd like to do it in command line. 
jar uf jar-file input-file(s) seemed to be good enough but my program doesn't work afterward

Comment: Looks like package issue. Both the classes are in 2 different packages. Therefore .class files should be in respective packages. Another issue is if you want to use class from different package, then **declare as public**